# unexpected token when building array of object using variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

Just feel strange why this will throw an error

```
var a = 'a';
var b = 'b';
const array = [{
  a + "&" + b
}, ];

console.log(array)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1qcjwwdn/

What I expect is just array `[{'a&b'}];` where a and b is variable.

Comment: an object has usually a key and a value.

Comment: and what is `{'a&b'}`? Because it does not look like  syntactically correct JS object

Comment: You cannot concatenate a string as an object key. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: `var array = [];` then use push `array.push({"key":"value"})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must name your property in object:

```
var a = 'a';
var b = 'b';
const array = [{PropertyName: a + "&" + b}];
```